# large time behavior for the Neumann problem for the heat equation

Tags: asymptotics, parabolic-pde, heat-equation

I am interested in the large time asymptotic behavior of parabolic equations. For instance, let $\Omega$ be a regular bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ . Let $g \in C(]0,+\infty[ \times \partial\Omega)$. Let
$$ \Omega^- \equiv \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \overline \Omega.$$
Consider the following exterior Neumann problem for the heat equation:

\begin{equation} 
\tag{NP}
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u -\Delta u = 0 \hspace{1cm} &\mbox{ in } ]0,+\infty[ \times\Omega^-,\\
\partial_\nu u=g &\mbox{ on } ]0,+\infty[ \times\partial\Omega^-,\\
u(0,\cdot) = 0 &\mbox{ in } \overline {\Omega^-}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I am wondering if there are known conditions on the Neumann datum $g$ which guarantee the physical solution $u$ of problem (NP) (the unique solution under the growth condition in space) to be bounded  or to have a limit as $t$ goes to $+\infty$ (by intuition I would say a condition on the integral of $g$). I am interested in the exterior problem, but to start I am also interested  in similar results for the interior one. 
To me it seems a quite classical question, so I am surprised that I couldn't find almost nothing in the literature. For example Friedman in his famous monograph "PDE of Parabolic Type" considers only the large time behavior for the Dirichlet problem and for a specific Robin problem ($\partial_\nu u(t,x)+f(t,x)u(t,x) = g(t,x)$ on $]0,+\infty[\times \partial \Omega$ with $f<-c$ for some c<0) which do not include the Neumann problem.

Comment: I do not know the literature, but for the interior problem the answer seems to be as follows. There is a unique up to a constant function $f$ in $\Omega$ such that $\partial_\nu f = g$ on $\partial \Omega$, and $\Delta f$ is constant, say $\lambda$, in $\Omega$. Then $v(t, x) = u(t, x) - f(x) + \lambda t$ satisfies the heat equation with the usual Neumann condition $\partial_\nu v = 0$.

Comment: I don't really get your argument. Can you expand it a little bit? Your point is that one can reduce my question to the problem with homogenous Neumann condition, which is well understood? Anyway the Neumann datum $g$ is time dependent, so I don't understand your assertion on the elliptic problem

Comment: The long-time behaviour of the corresponding problem with Dirichlet boundary conditions can be treated by using the theory of vector-valued Laplace transforms, see [Arendt et. al.: "Vector-Valued Laplaced Transforms and Cauchy Problems" (2011), Section 6.3]. Maybe the methods used there can also be employed to study Neumann boundary conditions?

Comment: @foo90: Ah, I did not notice that $g$ depends on time! Sorry. Yes, the idea was to switch to the homogeneous Neumann condition, but of course this no longer works when $g$ changes in time.